# ChartJS separate charts per JSON object, and not when hovered over

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I am very new to ChartJS and JavaScript, but I am trying to build some charts for my django app. I am having an issue when trying to build multiple charts from different JSON objects in the same string. Right now, the same chart is built, and when hovered over, it switches over to the second view. I want one chart with the first view, or first JSON object, and the second chart with the second view/second JSON object. See below for my code and some sample data:

```
data = [{'title': 'team', 'labels': ['Team score'], 'default': [50.0], 'title': 'single': 'labels': ['Single score'], 'default': [37.5]}]

JS:
var defaultData = [];
var labels = [];


function loadDashboard() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var objName = Object.keys(data)[0];
                    var val = data[key];
                    labels = val.labels;
                    defaultData = val.default;
                    updateChart(label=labels, data=defaultData, elementId=objName)
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(error_data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    });
}

function updateChart(label, data, elementId) {
    var tableName = document.getElementById(elementId).getContext('2d');
    var elementId = new Chart(tableName, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'NPS Score',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadDashboard()
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="teamScore" url-endpoint="{% url 'nps-dashboard-data' %}">
            <canvas id="teamScoreChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="singleScore">
            <canvas id="singeScoreChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/dashboard.js' %}"></script>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your for loop you're assigning both the contents of "team" and "single" to the same variables labels and defaultData. When you call updateChart you're creating both charts (in the loop, so twice). Chartjs doesn't handle that so well. Rather pass in parameters to updateChart like the element id, labels and data.

Comment: Hi @rory_za, thanks for the advice. I've tried to update it and edited in the new code, but now I am running into an issue where only 1 of the objects in data is passing the `if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))` check, so only 1 chart is showing up. Any ideas why? Sorry in advance for some big failures in the code :) - Completely new to web dev and JS in general!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out, for those interested:

```
var defaultData = [];
var labels = [];


function loadDashboard() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(data[key])
                    var val = data[key];
                    var objName = val['title']
                    labels = val.labels;
                    defaultData = val.default;
                    updateChart(labels, defaultData, objName)
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    });
}


function updateChart(label, data, elementId) {
    var newTable = document.getElementById(elementId).getContext('2d');
    var newElement = new Chart(newTable, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Score',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    loadDashboard()
});
```